# Cannot access xml file from a different domain

Tags: xml, cors

I am making a page where it needs to access information from an XML file.

The XML file "data.xml" is in a directory "news" in public_html in cpanel.

And the page which will access it is in a sub-domain in public_html.

Though i have given all the rights to read, write and execute the "data.xml" it still gives me the following error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://website.in/news/data.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://m.website.in' is therefore not allowed access.
```

after adding `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` to .htaccess file in directory `news` it still shows

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://springfest.in/news/data2.xml. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent cross-site scripting attacks, you are not allowed to access a resource from another domain *unless* `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` (as the error message states).

In addition, you'll need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept` to confirm that this kind of header is actually allowed.

How to allow cross-site access is dependent on your server software. For Apache, look at [this](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html). Otherwise, your favourite search engine will help you out.

Comment: You should consider giving a little bit more detailed answer.

Comment: please re-read the question, i have edited it, thanks for your help in advance.